wss issue with sfu-ion server
Problem Description
Running the sfu-ion server with TLS disabled,
Audio and video calling works on flutter client side as expected using the URL:
http://[domain_name]:5551
After enabling TLS using key file, the server runs without any error logs, and it appears operational. However, the Flutter client fails to connect, and no logs are shown on the server side when trying to connect using:
https://[domain_name]:5551
current sfu.toml
[global]
# data center id
dc = "dc1"

[nats]
url = "nats://nats:4222"

[sfu]
# Ballast size in MiB, will allocate memory to reduce the GC trigger upto 2x the
# size of ballast. Be aware that the ballast should be less than the half of memory
# available.
ballast = 0
# enable prometheus sfu statistics
withstats = false

[router]
# Limit the remb bandwidth in kbps
# zero means no limits
maxbandwidth = 1500
# max number of video tracks packets the SFU will keep track
maxpackettrack = 500
# Sets the audio level volume threshold.
# Values from [0-127] where 0 is the loudest.
# Audio levels are read from rtp extension header according to:
# https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6464
audiolevelthreshold = 40
# Sets the interval in which the SFU will check the audio level
# in [ms]. If the active speaker has changed, the sfu will
# emit an event to clients.
audiolevelinterval=1000
# Sets minimum percentage of events required to fire an audio level
# according to the expected events from the audiolevelinterval,
# calculated as audiolevelinterval/packetization time (20ms for 8kHz)
# Values from [0-100]
audiolevelfilter = 20

[router.simulcast]
# Prefer best quality initially
bestqualityfirst = true
# EXPERIMENTAL enable temporal layer change is currently an experimental feature,
# enable only for testing.
enabletemporallayer = false

[webrtc]
# Single port, portrange will not work if you enable this
singleport = 5000

# Range of ports that ion accepts WebRTC traffic on
# Format: [min, max]   and max - min >= 100
# portrange = [5000, 5200]
# if sfu behind nat, set iceserver
# [[webrtc.iceserver]]
# urls = ["stun:stun.stunprotocol.org:3478"]
# [[webrtc.iceserver]]
# urls = ["turn:turn.awsome.org:3478"]
# username = "awsome"
# credential = "awsome"

# sdp semantics:
# "unified-plan"
# "plan-b"
# "unified-plan-with-fallback"
sdpsemantics = "unified-plan"
# toggle multicast dns support: https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-mdns-ice-candidates-00
mdns = true

[webrtc.candidates]
# In case you're deploying ion-sfu on a server which is configured with
# a 1:1 NAT (e.g., Amazon EC2), you might want to also specify the public
# address of the machine using the setting below. This will result in
# all host candidates (which normally have a private IP address) to
# be rewritten with the public address provided in the settings. As
# such, use the option with caution and only if you know what you're doing.
# Multiple public IP addresses can be specified as a comma separated list
# if the sfu is deployed in a DMZ between two 1-1 NAT for internal and
# external users.
nat1to1 = ["45.45.45.45"] // public ip
icelite = true

[webrtc.timeouts]
# The duration in [sec] without network activity before a ICE Agent is considered disconnected
disconnected = 5
# The duration in [sec] without network activity before a ICE Agent is considered failed after disconnected
failed = 25
# How often in [sec] the ICE Agent sends extra traffic if there is no activity, if media is flowing no traffic will be sent
keepalive = 2

[turn]
# Enables embeded turn server
enabled = true
# Sets the realm for turn server
realm = "ion"
# The address the TURN server will listen on.
address = "0.0.0.0:3478"
# Certs path to config tls/dtls
# cert="path/to/cert.pem"
# key="path/to/key.pem"
# Port range that turn relays to SFU
# WARNING: It shouldn't overlap webrtc.portrange
# Format: [min, max]
# portrange = [5201, 5400]
[turn.auth]
# Use an auth secret to generate long-term credentials defined in RFC5389-10.2
# NOTE: This takes precedence over `credentials` if defined.
# secret = "secret"
# Sets the credentials pairs
credentials = "pion=ion,pion2=ion2"

[log]
# 0 - INFO 1 - DEBUG 2 - TRACE
v = 1

signal.toml
[global]
# data center id
dc = "dc1"

[log]
level = "info"
# level = "debug"

[nats]
url = "nats://nats:4222"

[signal.grpc]
#listen ip port
host = "0.0.0.0"
port = "5551"
allow_all_origins = true
cert= "configs/certs/cert.pem"
key= "configs/certs/key.pem"

[signal.jwt]
enabled = false 
key_type = "HMAC"  # this selects the Signing method https://godoc.org/github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go#SigningMethod
key = "1q2dGu5pzikcrECJgW3ADfXX3EsmoD99SYvSVCpDsJrAqxou5tUNbHPvkEFI4bTS"

[signal.svc]
services = ["rtc", "room"]

docker compose
version: "3.7"

services:
  islb:
    image: pionwebrtc/ion:latest-islb
    build:
      dockerfile: ./docker/islb.Dockerfile
      context: .
    volumes:
      - "./configs/docker/islb.toml:/configs/islb.toml"
    depends_on:
      - nats
      - redis
    networks:
      - ionnet

  sfu:
    image: pionwebrtc/ion:latest-sfu
    build:
      dockerfile: ./docker/sfu.Dockerfile
      context: .
    volumes:
      - "./configs/docker/sfu.toml:/configs/sfu.toml"
    ports:
      - "5000:5000/udp"
      - 3478:3478
    depends_on:
      - nats
      - islb
    networks:
      - ionnet

  signal:
    image: pionwebrtc/ion:latest-signal
    build:
      dockerfile: ./docker/signal.Dockerfile
      context: .
    volumes:
      - "./configs/docker/signal.toml:/configs/signal.toml"
      - "/etc/letsencrypt/archive/domain_name:/configs/certs"
    ports:
      - 5551:5551
    depends_on:
      - islb
      - app-room
    networks:
      - ionnet

  app-room:
    image: pionwebrtc/ion:latest-app-room
    build:
      dockerfile: ./docker/app-room.Dockerfile
      context: .
    volumes:
      - "./configs/docker/app-room.toml:/configs/app-room.toml"
    depends_on:
      - nats
      - redis
      - islb
    networks:
      - ionnet

  nats:
    image: nats
    ports:
      - 4222:4222
    networks:
      - ionnet

  redis:
    image: redis:6.0.9
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    networks:
      - ionnet

networks:
  ionnet:
    name: ionnet
    driver: bridge

** Additional Details **
The server uses a Certbot-generated certificate for TLS. No connection logs or errors are visible on either the server or the client when attempting the secure connection. Question: What might be causing the Flutter client not to connect when TLS is enabled, and how can I debug or resolve this issue?
